# How to register multiple implementations using factory pattern and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, factory

I have a factory method set up to return two different implementations of `IDeployApplicationService` based on a string value.

I've tried a few permutations of `.AddScoped()` or `.AddTransient()` in Program.cs but not sure why this error keeps persisting.

My factory

```csharp
public class DeployApplicationServiceFactory : IDeployApplicationServiceFactory
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        public DeployApplicationServiceFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public IDeployApplicationService GetService(string environment)
        {
            if (environment.ToLower() == "prod")
            {
                // Error thrown in the line below.
                // An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred 
                // in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll 
                // but was not handled in user code: 'No service for type 
                // 'ProdDeployApplicationService' has been registered.'

                return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ProdDeployApplicationService>();
            }
            else
            {
                return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<NonProdDeployApplicationService>();

            }
        }
    }
```

Program.cs (this is a worker)

```csharp
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>

    Host.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
         //[...]

         services.AddScoped<IDeployApplicationServiceFactory, DeployApplicationServiceFactory>();
         services.AddScoped<IDeployApplicationService, ProdDeployApplicationService>();
         services.AddScoped<IDeployApplicationService, NonProdDeployApplicationService>();

         //[...]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've registered the service **by its interface**:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IDeployApplicationService, ProdDeployApplicationService>()
```

This means you can only resolve it by the interface `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDeployApplicationService>()`, and that would give you the last service registered by that interface, `NonProdDeployApplicationService`.

Try registering it by itself (the implementation):

```cs
services.AddScoped<ProdDeployApplicationService>();
```

Now you can resolve the implementation directly:

```cs
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ProdDeployApplicationService>();
```

---

Keep in mind you can register a class multiple times: both by itself and by the interfaces/abstract classes it implements:

```cs
// this is ok
services.AddScoped<ProdDeployApplicationService>();
services.AddScoped<IDeployService, ProdDeployApplicationService>();
services.AddScoped<IDeployApplicationService, ProdDeployApplicationService>();
```

and resolve it using any key.